# convert html5 time input to another format

Tags: html, input, time, format

Is there a way to convert the html5 date input from one format to another?

For example: **2014-06-18 11:17:17** to  **18-06-2014 11:17:17** ?

Comment: Any reason, why not use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

Each browser shows it differently.

- Opera (Presto Engine) shows it the right way.
- Chrome (Webkit Engine) shows it in AM/PM.
- Firefox (Gecko Engine) doesn't show anything, but validates.

input `type=time` are based on an idea of localization that takes it all out of the hands of the page author. This is intentional; the problem has been raised in HTML5 discussions several times, with the same outcome: no change. (Except possibly added clarifications to the text, making this behavior described as intended.)

that you should use input type=text, with pattern attribute and with some JavaScript that checks the input for correctness on browsers that do not support the pattern attribute natively.